# Segment 3d mesh into multiple 3d meshes with equal size

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a 3d mesh, for example the [stanford bunny](http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/), how can I segment the mesh in a way that each segment has a roughly equal size between them? Assuming the target number of segments is given as an input.

To keep things simple, let's start with assuming the vertices are uniformly distributed in the mesh, therefore the problem can be simplified to segmenting the mesh so each segment has roughly the same vertices.

I've seen methods like finding a bounding box of the mesh, and divide the bounding box uniformly and segment the mesh based on that. But the problem with this method is the size of each segment can be quite different if the shape of the original mesh is irregular.

I've also seen a method based on [Shape Diameter Function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_segmentation/index.html), but again the size of each segment can be different depends on the original mesh.

The problem is I am not sure what's the right keyword to look up on Google to see what's being done in the literature. I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The purpose of mesh segmentation is better shape fitting, so they usually don't care about sizes of mesh segments. Why do you want sub-meshes of equal size?

Comment: @HEKTO it's mainly for compression purposes, same sizes of segments means no wastage for the corresponding texture.